# Ruby on Rails failed to push to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

There are so many stackoverflow posts on this issue but I do not know why I am not getting any to work. Here is what my gemfile looks like:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

git_source(:github) do |repo_name|
  repo_name = "#{repo_name}/#{repo_name}" unless repo_name.include?("/")
  "https://github.com/#{repo_name}.git"
end


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'
# Use sqlite3 as the database for Active Record
gem 'sqlite3'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 3.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
# See https://github.com/rails/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'autoprefixer-rails'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 3.0'
# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

gem 'sqlite3', :group => [:development, :test]
group :production do
  gem 'thin'
  gem 'pg'
end
group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

When I run `git push heroku master` it gives me an error saying that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.13'` is not available and needs to be installed(even though I have installed it).

I have tried deleteing the gem lock file, and bundleing and still nothing. I would love if someone was able to tell me where I am going wrong, because I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Maybe removing the `gem 'sqlite3'` (the one just below `gem 'rails', '~> 5.0.1'`).

Comment: you sir are a blessing!

Comment: That was the problem?

Comment: lol yeah it was

Comment: Great Aaron :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this article:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3

Sqlite is not supported by heroku as it uses an ephemeral filesystem so the database would be erased periodically.

You can use sqlite as a development database but you need to use something like

```
gem 'pg'
```

in production.  You can simply remove sqlite from your gemfile or move it to one of the development / test groups.

If you are using a database in your application you also need to set up the config/database.yml file with the correct configuration.